# LASSO with $L_p$ norms for $1 < p < 2$?

Tags: regression, references, lasso, sparse

For the sparse linear regression problem, minimizing the LASSO objective $\| X \beta - Y \|_2^2 + \lambda \| \beta \|_1$ is known to recover the optimal data generating parameter $\beta^*$ with the minimax sample complexity (assume that $Y_i = \langle X_i, \beta^* \rangle + Z_i$ where $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N} (0,1)$); for instance, see [here](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4839045?casa_token=NVJYD_TuuNIAAAAA:7AID6l9x_zaXwZ0txMI0LYFbhz9E5ujTjrZ_Z9a5Jbz6ndw1GBrVnpvTFFYROvr0fy1TYLNzBQ8).

Are there any results known about the sample complexity of the minimizer of a modified LASSO objective $\| X \beta - Y \|_2^2 + \lambda \| \beta \|_p$ for $1 < p < 2$? For instance, say with $p = 1.5$?

Comment: Do you mean to apply this modification as a sparse linear regression problem? You do not get an estimate $\hat\beta$ that is sparse when $p>1$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus That's true. But I am measuring the error as $\| \beta - \beta^* \|_2$: as long as one returns a parameter vector that is approximately sparse (by virtue of being close to $\theta^*$), that is fine.

Comment: but it will be different from the example in the link. Can you explain how you see it for the different case.